# Running shoes ruby 1.9.3 problems

Tags: ruby, user-interface, shoes, ruby-1.9.3

I have installed shoes successfully but when I run the command to start shoes`./dist/shoes`  I get this message `bash: ./dist/shoes: No such file or directory`
I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 and using ruby 1.9.3 rvm.
I installed shoes by following the instructions on this web page https://github.com/shoes/shoes/wiki/Building-Shoes-on-Linux

I get this error when I run rake

```
 gcc -I. -c -o shoes/world.o -Wall -I/usr/include -pthread 
-I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 
-I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 
-I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -pthread 
-I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 
-I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include 
-I/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux 
-I/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1 
-I/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1/i686-linux 
-O  -DRUBY_1_9 -DSHOES_GTK -fPIC -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 
-I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 
-I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 
-I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ 
-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include 
-I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 
shoes/world.c
shoes/world.c: In function ‘shoes_ruby_embed’:
shoes/world.c:92:11: warning: unused variable ‘sysinit_argv’ 
[-Wunused-variable]
gcc -I. -c -o shoes/image.o -Wall -I/usr/include -pthread 
-I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 
-I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 
-I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -pthread 
-I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 
-I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include 
-I/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux 
-I/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1 
-I/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1/i686-linux 
-O  -DRUBY_1_9 -DSHOES_GTK -fPIC -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 
-I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 
-I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 
-I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ 
-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include 
-I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 
shoes/image.c
shoes/image.c:31:21: fatal error: gif_lib.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [gcc -I. -c -o shoes/image.o -Wall 
-I/usr/i...]
Tasks: TOP => default => build => linux:build => old_build => build_os 
=> dist/shoes => dist/libshoes.so => shoes/image.o
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reinstalled ruby 1.9.3 rvm and shoes. This solved the problem and now shoes works.

Answer (score 2):

You have to be at your installation directory when you issue that command.

Does the executable `shoes` exists at that path? Is its executable bit set? Try it with `./dist/shoes <yourapp>`.

Based on the output it seems [libgif-dev](http://packages.debian.org/en/sid/armhf/libgif-dev/filelist) is not installed (you are missing lib_gif.h which [is](https://shoesknowledge.com/) part of that package.)

There is a line in the manual with the prerequisite packages for Ubuntu, install those, and retry installing shoes.

Comment: ./dist/shoes doesn't exist in the shoes directory

Comment: Then your installation was not a success :-) Can you reinstall it and paste some output? Which Shoes did you install? Red Shoes (http://shoes.heroku.com/) or Green Shoes (https://github.com/ashbb/green_shoes)?

Comment: okay, then try the installation steps again (for Ubuntu), and paste what `rake` outputs to screen into your question.